# how to make text positioned in columns

Tags: html, css

I have some columns I made with CSS. I want to know if I can make the text flow into columns, so that the text is like this:

```html
<style>
th{border:1px solid black; border-bottom:none;}
     td{border-collapse:collapse;}
    </style>
    <table>
      <th colspan="2"> Header</th>
      <th colspan="2"> Header</th>
      
      <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
        <td style="border:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid gray;">Content</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid gray;">Content</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid gray;">Content</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid gray;">Content</td>
      </tr>
```

Each header spans two columns. I would prefer to do this without tables.

Comment: Why don't you want to use tables? They seem to be perfect for this situation.

Comment: @MathNerdProductions Tables are not perfect in this situation, tables should only contain tabular data, not content.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin You realize that answer links to posts that are more than a decade old, right? The question itself is more than 7 years old. Regardless, there is nothing *wrong* with using tables where they are efficient and easy to modify in the future. Where you get into trouble is in excess: nesting and the like.

Comment: @MathNerdProductions It is an old post however it also contains a flushed out argument for the pros and cons of using tables in varying conditions. I admit tables won't crash anything however the best case with tables is the worst case with divs. Both take roughly the same amount of time to setup while `div`s are easier to change later. Oh and apperantly `tables` do not translate into screen readers well, however I have not experienced that.

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqsthewm/)

See here to find out when to use tables: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

The layout can be created with the following code, however if you wanted to `overflow text into two columns` then you will need to look into Javascript / jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="header">Header one</div>
  <div class="header">Header Two</div>

  <div class="quarter">Content One </div>
  <div class="quarter">Content Two</div>
  <div class="quarter">Content Three</div>
  <div class="quarter">Content Four</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
  display:block;
  background-color:grey;
  width:80%;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:0pt;
}

.header{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:12pt;
  width:48%;
  margin:1%;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.quarter{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:12pt;
  width:23%;
  min-height:40px;
  margin:1%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: I know it works in the fiddle, but it doesn't work in my site: http://www.sarkelliancreed.comule.com. Click on "Tutorials and Snippets" at the top of the page.

Comment: Add `font-size:0pt;` to `<div id="snippet-dropdown" class="dropdown" style="display: block; z-index: 200;">` and it works for your site too.